# Check if a text string contains text or similar text

Tags: python, text, nlp, data-science, textmatching

I have an interesting problem:

I have a fairly large paragraph of text, and I want to check if the paragraph contains certain phrases. Now, direct matching is not allowed as I want to know whether the paragraph contains the phrases OR similar phrases, e.g. if I have a privacy policy document, and I want to check if the document mentions anything about "tracking cookies", how will I go about this?

I am doing it in Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could build a regular expression that captures multiple variants of the string "tracking cookies". For example, a regex that captures:

```
tracking cookies
cookie trackers
Cookies
cookie
tracker cookie
Tracking Cookies
.
.
.
etc.
```

Then, every time you encounter a new variant of your string, you can add it to the regular expression.

Comment: How will I go about it?

Comment: Look up "Regular Expressions in Python". I (and no one else on this site) will write code for you. If you get stuck, look up answers on Stack Overflow and elsewhere online. If you then cannot find the answer, ask a new question on Stack Overflow. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks a lot Alexandru Cristiean. To be clear, I did not ask for code, I asked for a logical explanation, rather than the hint you gave. Either way, I figured it out. Thanks.

Comment: I accepted it as the answer, I unfortunately cannot upvote as I am a fairly new member. Thank you Alexandru!